# Craft 3 paginate not working when fetched with a controller

Tags: templating, ajax, modules, controller, pagination

I'm loading a paginate via `Craft::$app->getView()->renderTemplate()`, this is being executed within a controller. But my pageInfo.nextUrl is now the url of my controller (/actions/controllername/default/p2) is there a way to fix this or am i doing something terribly wrong here?

The complete routing is:

1. /paginationurl
2. fetching new pagination lists with ajax with the help of a controller (templates are _private)
3. url output is of the pageInfo is now the action url of this controller

Answer (score 2):

After leaving this issue for a day I found an article referring to the docs
[setBasePath](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-web-twig-variables-paginate.html#method-setbasepath)

```
{% paginate queryLeden as pageInfo, pageEntries %}
{% if craft.app.request.isAjax %}
    {% do pageInfo.setBasePath('YOURBASEURL') %}
{% endif %}
```

Hope this helps someone else :)